# R: Strategy to deal with "double sum of three number product"

Tags: r

Suppose the matrix A has 5000 rows and 6000 columns, where each element is `a_ij` and there is another matrix S, which has 6000 rows and 6000 columns and it is a symmetrical matrix, in which each element is `s_lk`, i would like to calculate `m_ij = sum(k=1..6000, l=1..6000)(a_il * a_jk * s_lk)`, (i.e., [this formula](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5nw7ha5j8pkgcr9/sum.pdf?dl=0)), which should be 5000 * 5000 matrix. What is a good trick to do such problem (double sum for multiple number product)? Should we simplify it first?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Wait a minute. Didn't we see an identical question a couple of days ago???

Comment: I guess you are looking for `a %*% S %*% t(a)`

Comment: that is two number product. there is a little different, but for me, I still can not solve the current question.

Comment: If you want this reopened you need to explain why there is an identical question from you with an accepted answer.

Comment: @BondedDust, the two questions are not same, as the original one was answered: `x <- rowSums(a); x %o% x`, and for this question, @nicola may give the right answer.

Comment: @nicola, can give me a further explanation about how do you deal with the formula and give this answer? `a %*% S %*% t(a)`. I am in trouble to deal with the double summation for multiple products. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you know that if `A = BC` (where A,B,C are matrices) you have that `a_ij = \sum_k b_ik*c_kj`, it's easy to prove that you can obtain your formula from what I wrote in my comment. Just remember that `a_jk = t(a)_kj`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@nicola, nicola gave the right anwser. thank you.

`A %*% S %*% t(A)`

Here I just post nicola's answer. If it is not suitable, please delete it.